# How to pass variables from one view controller to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created a bottom slide up view controller for a main view controller, but I'm not sure how to pass information from the main view controller to the slide up one.  I have a button in the main view controller that can show or hide the slide up view controller, and I want to use the button to pass information.  The code below is the IBAction for the button which would show/hide the slide up view controller, but without a segue I'm not sure how to pass anything.

```
- (IBAction)btnMoveToShowBottomView:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = sender;

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0:
            [_delegate moveToHideBottomTableView];
            break;

        case 1:
           BottomTableViewController *tableScreen = [[BottomTableViewController alloc]...];
        tableScreen.photoDesc = selectedPhotoDesc;
        [_delegate moveToShowBottomTableView];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In the code above I've tried to access the slide up view controller (with a class called BottomTableViewController), but there seems to be a problem because it is asking for an expected expression when I attempt to access an object in that class (an NSString called photoDesc).

Comment: What is the `[_delegate moveToShowBottomTableView]` for? If you're trying to present a new view controller without a segue you should call  `presentViewController` (the delegate shouldn't have to handle this). Regardless, the error you're getting sounds like it doesn't know where you're getting `selectedPhotoDesc` from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotification mechanism:

In a controller that has to get param register for notification:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificaitonCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(handleParam:) name:@"myNotification" object: nil];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
- (void)handleParam:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"myNotification")
    {
        id myParam = notification.object;
    }
}
```

In a controller that has to send a parameter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object: myObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
1)  https://medium.com/@jigarm/nsuserdefaults-iphone-objective-c-514febbbf29b

2)  Have you tried passing

```
    self
```

and

```
    selectedPhotoDesc
```

to the function

```
    moveToShowBottomTableView
```